# concatenate characters in new string then convert them in integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
number="0123,456,789,"
cleanedNumber=''

for i in range(0,len(number)):
    if number[i] in '0123456789':
        cleanedNumber = cleanedNumber + number[i]


newNumber = int(cleanedNumber)
print("The number is {}".format(newNumber))
```

I don't understand why do we use variable `cleanedNumber=''`?

Comment: you didn't write this snippet? What would your guess be as to why the `cleanedNumber` name is used?

Comment: cleanedNumber holds "sanitez" string that contains digits only. If this is what you intend to do, (filtering digits only), a one line regex is the correct solution,

Comment: Because you clean the number of anything not in "0123456789", like " " and ",".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `for` loop, the original string stored in `number` is looped character by character.

`cleanedNumber` string is used to store digits only. Everything that is not a digit (i.e. a character from 0 to 9) will not be added to the `cleanedNumber` string. At the end of the `for` loop, only characters that are digits are kept in this new variable.

Finally, it is converted to an integer and displayed.

Comment: is it right to understand variable cleanNumber as something that will prevent,default new line when characters are being printed?

Comment: No, you can look at `cleanNumber` as the same as `number` but where you keep numbers only.

Answer (score 1):

It can be a lot easier than that. Just do:

```
newNumber = int(filter(str.isdigit, number))
```

Or, alternatively:

```
newNumber = int(number.replace(",", ""))
```

Comment: This won't *really* help when the OP can barely read the code snippet he provided.

Comment: This doesn't work on Python 3.3.  `TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'filter'`

Answer (score 0):

The original code simply creates a new string variable to store the "sanitized" or "cleaned" version of the original input.

We start off with a string:

```
number="0123,456,789,"
```

Then the originator decided to copy the "numbers" into another string variable:

```
cleanedNumber=''
```

To achieve this, a for loop was written just to read every string member:

```
  for i in range(0,len(number)):
    if number[i] in '0123456789':
        cleanedNumber = cleanedNumber + number[i]
```

The translation of this would be that for each "i" in the range from 0 to the length of the original string, we check if the value of "i" from the "number" string variable is present in '0123456789'. If it is present, then we copy it in the "cleanedNumber" variable.

In the end, the code converts it to an int and prints it:

```
newNumber = int(cleanedNumber)
print("The number is {}".format(newNumber))
```

There are simpler ways of writing this code though.